# QGIS rule-based labelling based on active symbology

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a layer with rule-based symbols and rule-based labeling. Only one symbol group is supposed to be active at a time and the corresponding label should be activated. Can I link the labels to the symbols (similar to "is_layer_visible")?
[image: snippet of Rule-Based Symbology]

[image: snippet of Rule-Based Labels]